# R language - when using simple c(2,3,4) combine function .. error occurs

Tags: r, runtime-error

R language:

> x<-c(2,3,4)
>   Error in c(2, 3, 4) : unused arguments (3, 4)

It actually computes the square function as given below..
function(x){x*x}

> c(8)
>   [1] 64
>   It seems that during practice I have inadvertently defined a function
>   c<- function(x){x*x}

Now, whenever I am using c() command in my program to combine the arguments, it throws up the error as stated above.
How should I resolve this issue so as to get the default function of c()

Comment: Errr, maybe just restart your R session?

Answer (score 1):

No need to restart your R session -- you can reload the function definition from the package namespace where it is defined, in this case `base`.

```
c(2, 3, 4)
c = function(x) x*x
c(2, 3, 4)  # error
c = base::c
c(2, 3, 4)
```